# Get address of the page from which redirected to new page

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get previous page URL after Response.Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805438/get-previous-page-url-after-response-redirect)

Suppose in page 1.aspx, if error occurs, I'm using in catch() block:

```
Response.Redirect("err.aspx");
```

In code behind of err.aspx, I need url of 1.aspx (or any page from which I'm redirecting to err.aspx page). How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why dont you create customer error pages, cause then you will get all the info you need without passing it allong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Page.Request.UrlReferrer; also you can add it as the redirect query parameter, or put into the session, if the referrer doesnt work somehow. see [Get previous page URL after Response.Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805438/get-previous-page-url-after-response-redirect)

Answer (score 3):

You can get them as

```
if( !IsPostBack )
{
   if(Request.UrlReferrer != null)
   {
     ViewState["PreviousPageUrl"] = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Answer (score 0):

```
    Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```

It will redirect you to previous page automatically from where you have came on current page...

Answer (score -1):

You should have a look here

On how to create custom error pages
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/Displaying-a-Custom-Error-Page-cs