# How to Find previous page after page redirect done using Response.Redirect?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7

I am redirecting user from one page(`EditUser.aspx`) to another page(`UserDeatils.aspx`) like

```
Response.Redirect("UserDetails.aspx")
```

How can I find page one i.e `EditUser.aspx` in 2nd page.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805438/get-previous-page-url-after-response-redirect) we have similar issue, but I cannot use this method as 1st page name cannot be sent in query string.

Comment: You want to access controls of `EditUser` in `UserDetails`? Then use `Server.Transfer` and [`Page.PreviousPage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks Tim, I don't want to access EditUser control in UserDetails page. Just I want to know the page name/URL from which I get redirected to User Details page.

Comment: Here are some ideas that can help you:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=89

Comment: which .Net Framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use below line:

`string PrePageName=Request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath;`